# Change column width of a table in a Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, multiple-columns, google-docs

Someone knows what is wrong here? I have another code that has this exact code and works!

```
 var dados = sheet.getRange('B10:D19');
  var tabela = [[]];
  tabela.push(['Quem', 'Quanto', 'Onde']);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(1, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(1, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(1, 3).getValue()]);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(2, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(2, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(2, 3).getValue()]);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(3, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(3, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(3, 3).getValue()]);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(4, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(4, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(4, 3).getValue()]);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(5, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(5, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(5, 3).getValue()]);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(6, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(6, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(6, 3).getValue()]);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(7, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(7, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(7, 3).getValue()]);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(8, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(8, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(8, 3).getValue()]);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(9, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(9, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(9, 3).getValue()]);
  tabela.push([dados.getCell(10, 1).getValue(), formatThousands(dados.getCell(10, 2).getValue()), dados.getCell(10, 3).getValue()]);

  body.appendParagraph('Últimos gastos:');
  var tabelaDoc = body.appendTable(tabela);
  tabelaDoc.setColumnWidth(0, 50);
  tabelaDoc.setColumnWidth(1, 80);
```

The error message is:

```
Child index (0) must be less than the number of child elements (0).Dismiss
```

PS: The table appears normally on Document

Comment: Probably your `setColumnWidth` should work with a 1-based index instead of a zero-based. First column is "1" instead of zero.

Comment: Same error: `Child index (1) must be less than the number of child elements (0).Dismiss`

Comment: Well, since the number changed, it is probably the right place. Are you sure the `tabelaDoc` contains any column? (Try `tabelaDoc.getRange`, for instance).

Comment: `Logger.log(tabelaDoc.getRange)` returned `[15-06-05 11:46:04:770 BRT] undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Simply change your table var to `var tabela = [];`

You are already pushing an array into another, that makes it 2D.
Forget about the index 1. It seems it's zero based indeed.